# How can I remove the blue border/outline from UITableViews in a mac app built with UIKitForMac?

Tags: ios, macos, uitableview, uikit, uikitformac

This screenshot is taken from an app built for mac with UIKitForMac. The blue outline appears whenever you tap on any cell in a UITableView or highlight any text in a UITextView.

[image: Screenshot of my app which shows a blue outline]

**Reproduce:**

1. Go to a UITableView
2. Select a cell
3. (if this takes you to another view, tap the back button)
4. See the blue outline

How can I stop this blue outline from ever showing up?

**Additional Context**

If I turn on the view debugger, it disappears before I can debug it.

Comment: This is probably a bug in Beta 5; Apple’s Home app exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep an eye on it and see if it gets fixed.

Comment: Fixed for table views in Beta 7. Text fields/views still have outlines.

Comment: Yep, verified. Thanks.